# Counter in fancyhdr not matching body

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, counters

I'm trying to set a counter that says "x of 3" at the right header where x increments based on when I use \pgroup. However it shows "2 of 3" on the first page and then "3 of 3" on the second and third pages. When I use `\lipsum` instead of `Sample text` it works the way I want it to.
I couldn't find any results from Google searches, but maybe I'm using the wrong keywords.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[head=50pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcounter{pgroup}
\setcounter{pgroup}{1}
\newcommand{\pgroup}{\stepcounter{pgroup} \newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}}
\newcommand{\numgroups}{3}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{Homework 9}
\rhead{\arabic{pgroup} of \numgroups}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Sample text. Pgroup: \arabic{pgroup}
    \item Sample text. Pgroup: \arabic{pgroup}
    \pgroup
    \item Sample text. Pgroup: \arabic{pgroup}
    \pgroup
    \item Sample text. Pgroup: \arabic{pgroup}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you set the `page` counter to 1 within `\pgroup`?

Comment: To have the page numbers restart; my professor wants three groups of problems so I figured it'd make sense to have the numbering restart.

Answer (score 3):

Your code sequence does the following:

```
\setcounter{pgroup}{1}
```

This sets `pgroup` to be one. In the list

```
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Sample text. Pgroup: \arabic{pgroup}
    \item Sample text. Pgroup: \arabic{pgroup}
    \pgroup
    \item Sample text. Pgroup: \arabic{pgroup}
    \pgroup
    \item Sample text. Pgroup: \arabic{pgroup}
  \end{enumerate}
```

no page is output until the first `\pgroup`, which does

```
\newcommand{\pgroup}{\stepcounter{pgroup} \newpage \setcounter{page}{1}}
```

So it steps `pgroup` *first* (now it will represent two), before shipping out the page (via `\newpage`). Since headers/footers form part of the page style which is only written during page shipout, `\arabic{pgroup}` would print `2`.

The same happens with the subsequent call to `\pgroup`, stepping `pgroup` to three before shipping out the page. The final page is shipped out at the end of the document without a call to `\pgroup`, leaving `pgroup` untouched.

The above only explains the behaviour. However, since I'm unfamiliar with what you're trying too achieve exactly, I can't suggest much more but to switch the stepping and `\newpage` reference in `\pgroup`:

```
\newcommand{\pgroup}{\newpage \stepcounter{pgroup} \setcounter{page}{1}}
```